# Send ajax request on scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to send ajax request when my page is first time scrolled to 20% of the actual height of the page .I have tried this but this is not working .

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.2){
        sendajax();
    }
});
```

Please suggest me what i have done wrong.I have to send only first time when scrolled to 20%

Comment: is the equation right? Should it be `$(document).height() * 0.2`

Comment: i have checked both but it is not working @stanley1943

Comment: I tried this for the stackoverflow page itself... I just put an alert...seems to be working

Comment: @Gaurav whats problem?is ajax is not calling or something else?(Actually  its working at my end)stanley1943: equation is correct as Gaurav wants to call AJAX after scroll ing of 20% of page.

Comment: Ajax function is getting called for many times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are calling `sendajax()` on `$(window).scroll(function()`.

So every time you scrolled page it will check your condition in that block. After 20% your condition `if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.2)` always gone be true so it will call `sendajax()` every time you scroll page (after 20%).

probable solution is you may set flag inside condition block like

```
var isAjaxCalled= false; 
$(window).scroll(function(){
if (($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.2) && !isAjaxCalled){
isAjaxCalled= true; 
    sendajax();
}
});
```

This may helps you.

thanks